# Error domain NSPOSIXErrorDomain on app resume

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection, cfstream, nsurlerrordomain

My app needs to refresh content on resume. I am using CFStream API to connect to our servers.

A few times, I get the NSPOSIXErrorDomain error with error code 9, when the app resumes even though there is an internet connection.

Is there anything special I should be doing on resume, such as wait a bit before trying to connect? Also, is there anything special I should be doing on suspend (either by screen lock button or home button)?